# Is it possible to use a loop inside an inline object declaration?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Where `ListOfComment` is a `List<Comment>` property of an object, what is best way to do this:

```
                        ListOfComment = new List<Comment>
                        {
                            foreach(object a in b)
                            {
                                new Comment
                                {
                                    Type = "",
                                    Description = ""
                                }
                            }
                        }
```

Comment: why don't you simply try to compile it? you already spent more time wrinting this post, then trying to do compialtion.

Comment: Place it outside the collection initializer and simply use `ListOfComment.Add()`?

Comment: @JeroenVannevel That belongs as an answer, not as a comment. But do note that the question has `ListOfComment` as a property, and because of that, the property setter would see an empty list and possibly act on it before the caller wants.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not *directly*, but you could do:

```
ListOfComment = b.Select(a => new Comment {
    Type = "",
    Description = ""
}).ToList();
```

or:

```
ListOfComment = (from a in b
                 select new Comment {
                     Type = "",
                     Description = ""
                 }).ToList();
```

or:

```
ListOfComment = new List<Comment>(b.Select(a => new Comment {
    Type = "",
    Description = ""
}));
```

or:

```
ListOfComment = new List<Comment>(
    from a in b
    select new Comment {
        Type = "",
        Description = ""
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

Probably to use LINQ:

```
ListOfComment = b.Select(a => new Comment{ Type="", Description=""}).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible inside an object Declaration, you can do this

```
var comments = (from a in b
                select new Comment
                {
                     Type = "",
                     Description = "";
                }).ToList();
```

What you can do is this (with a fixed number of entries)

```
var comments = new List<Comment>()
{
    new Comment { Type= "", Description = "" },
    new Comment { Type= "", Description = "" },
};
```